# Php Shopping Cart Issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to fix a php issue in an awm shop plugin for wordpress which is probably quite straight forward but my php skills are not the best and my attempts at resolving have led to no success.

I have a shopping cart set up so that:

Shipping is always free for aus residents
Shipping is $15 for non residents but free if they order > $500

With the following code:

```
foreach( $cart_items as $items ) {
        if( $items['type'] == "purchase" ) {
            $amount = $amount + ( $items['price'] * $items['quantity'] );
        }else{
            $amount = $amount + ( $items['price'] * $items['quantity'] );
        }
    }

    $country = "";

    if( $order_details['billing_not_shipping'] ){
        $country = $order_details['shipping_country'];
    }else{
        $country = $order_details['billing_country'];
    }

    if( strtolower($country) == "australia" )
    {
        $this_quote = $simple_shipping_options[1]['order_fee'];
        foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
            $this_quote += $cart_item['quantity'] * $simple_shipping_option['product_fee'];
        }
        $return_quotes[] = array(
            'name' => $simple_shipping_options[1]['name'],
            'total' => $this_quote,
        );
    }
    else
    {
        if( $amount > 500 ) {
            $this_quote = $simple_shipping_options[0]['order_fee'];
            foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
                $this_quote += $cart_item['quantity'] * $simple_shipping_option['product_fee'];
            }
            $return_quotes[] = array(
                'name' => "Free Shipping for any order over $500",
                'total' => $this_quote,
            );
        }else{
            $this_quote = $simple_shipping_options[1]['order_fee'];
            foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
                $this_quote += $cart_item['quantity'] * $simple_shipping_option['product_fee'];
            }
            $return_quotes[] = array(
                'name' => $simple_shipping_options[1]['name'],
                'total' => $this_quote,
            );
        }
    }

    return $return_quotes;
}
```

And

```
<table class="form-table awms_settings_shipping_simple">
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><label for="aus_residents">Free Shipping within Australia</label></td>
    <td><input name="shipping_custom_order_fee[]" type="text" id="aus_residents" value="<?php echo $shipping_custom[1]["order_fee"] ?>" />$ AUD</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_custom_name[]" value="Free shipping within Australia" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><label for="aus_not_residents">Outside Australia</label></td>
    <td><input name="shipping_custom_order_fee[]" type="text" id="aus_not_residents" value="<?php echo $shipping_custom[1]["order_fee"]; ?>" /> $ AUD</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_custom_name[]" value="Outside Australia" />
</tr>
```

Does anyone know how to set it up so that it is the same for both situations?

Comment: Your logic looks correct. What is the issue you're having?

Comment: It works perfectly for every country except Australia. For Australia it is always free i.e. $0 and I need the same rule that applies to every other country to apply to asutralian too. So if it's <500 it charges amount and if its >500 it charges $0. Let me know if it's not clear!

Comment: Well, then you're probably multiplying the total by the shipping fee - are you?

Comment: I don't think so no. The shipping fee is an amount that is added at the end set to $15. I've added a bit of code above if that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

hmm i think you just need to take the if Australia statement out?

change

`if( strtolower($country) == "australia" )`

to

`if( strtolower($country) == "australiaX" )`

To ignore the statement.. or

```
/*    if( strtolower($country) == "australia" )
    {
        $this_quote = $simple_shipping_options[1]['order_fee'];
        foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
            $this_quote += $cart_item['quantity'] * $simple_shipping_option['product_fee'];
        }
        $return_quotes[] = array(
            'name' => $simple_shipping_options[1]['name'],
            'total' => $this_quote,
        );
    }
    else
    {
*/ 
       if( $amount > 500 ) {
            $this_quote = $simple_shipping_options[0]['order_fee'];
            foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
                $this_quote += $cart_item['quantity'] * $simple_shipping_option['product_fee'];
            }
            $return_quotes[] = array(
                'name' => "Free Shipping for any order over $500",
                'total' => $this_quote,
            );
        }else{
            $this_quote = $simple_shipping_options[1]['order_fee'];
            foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
                $this_quote += $cart_item['quantity'] * $simple_shipping_option['product_fee'];
            }
            $return_quotes[] = array(
                'name' => $simple_shipping_options[1]['name'],
                'total' => $this_quote,
            );
        }
/*    }*/

    return $return_quotes;
```

Comment: I tried that alright but it still seems to be applying the free shipping to australia. I'll add the form table that allows me to change the shipping amount in wordpress but ive tried editing that too and I'm having no joy. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($simple_shipping_options);`

Comment: It seems to break the whole cart when I comment that bit out for some reason actually. Thanks for the suggestion though I thought that would do it too.

Comment: OK in that case, on your existing code just change `if( strtolower($country) == "australia" )` to `if( strtolower($country) == "australiaX" )` so that it ignores the statement.. see if it then applies the rule you wanted

Comment: For some reason it's still applying that rule. I'm stumped at the moment because I've tried different ways to try to get it to ignore the statement but can't. I'm stumped! Thanks for trying

Comment: you know what, it is ignoring that statement.. however the calculation for that fee is the same for if its Australia and not Australia.. so i suspect something is up with `$simple_shipping_options` - what array does it print out when you do `print_r($simple_shipping_options);`